# Recursive SQL Query. Select last entry grouping by

Tags: mysql

I have a Rates table with destinations, prices and effective_dates for this prices.

I want to get a list of a destination with last prices.

Example table:

```
Destination  | Code | Effective_date | Price
Spain        | 34   | 2013-04-05     | 0.02
Spain        | 34   | 2013-07-01     | 0.01
Spain Mobile | 346  | 2013-04-05     | 0.07
Spain Mobile | 346  | 2013-07-01     | 0.08
```

For example, if I search code 34 I want to get Spain 2013-07-01 and Spain Mobile 2013-07-01
I try with

```
SELECT * 
FROM carrier_fares AS cf1               
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM carrier_fares AS cf2
    WHERE code LIKE ?
    AND cf1.effective_date < cf2.effective_date
    )
```

The table have above 50.000 entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT x.*
     FROM carrier_fares x
     JOIN  
        ( SELECT destination
               , MAX(effective_date) max_date 
            FROM carrier_fares 
           GROUP 
              BY destination
        ) y
       ON y.destination = x.destination 
      AND y.max_date = x.effective_date

-- [WHERE code LIKE '34%']
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM carriers_fares ORDER BY effective_date DESC
) as t1 GROUP by effective_date, code
```